# Why queue bindings does not work in Azure?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I'm trying to create a function with a queue trigger, here's the `function.json`:

```
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "CraigslistItemParser",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "craigslist",
      "connection": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

When deploying the function in the console logs I get the error:

```
The 'CraigslistItemParser' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.CraigslistItemParser'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection string 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.
```

What is the App Setting, I can’t find them anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reading the documentation it looks like you can't specify a connection string directly in the "connection" setting. Instead, you must include "**the name of an app setting** that contains the Storage connection string to use for this binding."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---configuration